# Make table cell(TD) have dotted background

Tags: html, css

Is it possible in HTML 4 to make a table td cell have a dotted background?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - CSS3 pixelate dot background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607117/css-css3-pixelate-dot-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can e.g. create an image with a dotted background and set it as background image on a `td` element. This is possible even in HTML using the `background` attribute on a `td` tag; it works well, though it is formally non-conforming. So people usually recommend using CSS instead (specifically, the `background-image` property or the `background` shortcut property).